# How can I access an array in another class via a pointer to that array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Usually in order to access a member variable of a class/object from a different class, you would use the arrow operator (->). In this case I would like to access an array, however the size of the array is only known at runtime, therefore I can't declare the array in the header file of the class. In fact, I only declare the array in the class constructor.

I still need to be able to access this array from a different class. I'm attempting to do this by declaring a pointer in the header file of the first class, and then after the array is declared and initialised, have that pointer point to the first element of the array.

The header file station.h:

```
class TokenPool {
public:
    TokenPool(int K);
    ~TokenPool();
       ...
public:
    int K;
    int *pointToPool;
};
```

Then in station.cpp:

```
TokenPool::TokenPool(int K) {
    this->K = K;
    cout << "K = " << this->K << " in tokenPool" << "\n";
    int pool[K];

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        pool[i] = i+1;
        cout << pool[i] << " tokens in class " << i << "\n";
    }

    pointToPool = pool;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that K=1.
The problem is when I attempt to access the array from a different class like so:

```
cout << "class " << this->k << " has " << *(station1->tokenPool->pointToPool+0) << " tokens.\n";
```

It produces strange output like so:

```
class 0 has 31156208 tokens.
```

Where, if K=1, it should actually show:

```
class 0 has 1 tokens.
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Usually you wouldn't. Besides, there's an UB in your code.

Comment: `int pool[K];` -- This isn't valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<int> pool(K);`  The second thing is that even with all of this `int pool[K]` and even `std::vector<int> pool` are local variables.  What will you be pointing to when the function returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TokenPool::TokenPool(int K) {
    ...
    int pool[K];
    ...
    pointToPool = pool;
}
```

`pool` is declared on the stack, so it ceases to exist as soon as the constructor returns. You assign its address to `this->pool`, but the address no longer points into valid memory. Subsequently reading from this pointer results in undefined behaviour.

The C++ way is generally to avoid raw arrays, and use `std::vector` instead. It makes the code both simpler and safer, and hardly any less efficient:

```
#include <vector>

class TokenPool {
public:
    TokenPool(int K);
    ~TokenPool();
       ...
public:
    std::vector<int> pool;
};

TokenPool::TokenPool(int K) :
    pool(K)
{
    cout << "K = " << this->K << " in tokenPool" << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        pool[i] = i+1;
        cout << pool[i] << " tokens in class " << i << "\n";
    }
}
```